# Best Practice Azure DB Scaling

Tags: database, azure, synchronization, azure-sql-database

I have a webapplication running in the azure cloud. Currently we only use the Region "West Europe" but we will now add US as a region too.

Now i'm thinking about the database... 
Currently i have the Azure SQL Database in the Region West Europe.
it is a very small database and does not contain a large amount of data. There are mostly only relations, userdata and other stuff like that in it.

So what would now be the best practice to scale it to multiple regions?

I think i have the following options:

- Leaf the database in that region and connect from other regions to the same database (here i fear mostly latency issues)
- Create a database for each region and work with Database synchronisation

Regarding the database synchronisation i could not find an answer which would explain what would happen in the following situation:

Initial State (both are sync):

Region A, Table A

id value

1  "test"

2  "test2"

3  "test3"

Region B, Table A

id value

1  "test"

2  "test2"

3  "test3"

Now data is added in both databases:

Region A, Table A

id value

1  "test"

2  "test2"

3  "test3"

4  "test4"

5  "test5"

Region B, Table A

id value

1  "test"

2  "test2"

3  "test3"

4  "test6"

5  "test7"

In the Documentation they always talk about if a row has been updated then the specific Rule "Hub wins" or "Client wins" apply. But what will happen in this situation where rows where added?
i believe that the final outcome after the sync will be (if hub wins is selected and the Hub is the Database in Region A):

4  "test4"

5  "test5"

So all changes in Region B will be ignored. is that right?
The PK in this table is an integer. Maybe this problem can be solved if the PK is a Guid i guess...

I'm currently not sure, what would be the best way to scale the database. I hope that somebody could give me a hint.
Does anybody have already experienced how the latency is inside the Azure Network accross multiple regions?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you are correct on the bi-directional Azure DB sync - in your case, after the sync, Region B will be updated as the same as Region A according to the conflict resolution setting.

To scale out your app while allowing active-active, you need to make sure the PK is unique in each region, e.g. using GUID or well partitioned. If your app is read-intensive, another option is to redirect all the write operation to a single "master" DB, then push the changes to other read-only regions; it can avoid conflict, but need app logic change though.

(BTW, please note that Azure Data Sync is eventual consistency but not transactional consistency, and it's scheduled instead of continuous. You'd better to evaluate if your app can tolerate these.)

Regarding the network latency across regions, there is a 3rd party site [azurespeed.com](http://azurespeed.com) with nice visualization that may help, though not specifically for Azure DB.

Comment: thank you, i took a deeper look into all this because DB scaling is something i have been spared yet :). i found that Azure Elastic DB might be the thing that i need. There i can create Shards (it looks like also in different Regions) and with that i can distribute the load and keep the latency in the regions to a minimum.